# Why does transitioning from width: 100% cause the transition to be jumpy?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-grid

I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2vpc07ju/2/) to reenact this problem.

I am trying to get a grid element to grow when hovered, but it causes this weird problem where it goes under the other grid element, then jumps to how I expected and want it to be.

Why does this happen and is there a way to get around it?

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr / 1fr 1fr;
  margin: 1em;
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

.box {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}

.one {
  background: pink;
}

.two {
  background: red;
}

.box:hover {
  width: 60vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box one"></div>
  <div class="box two"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `grid-template: 1fr / 1fr 1fr` creates two columns of equal width (and one row). The `.box` -es are set to be as wide as their parent, which they can't since they must share half the space with their sibling. What exactly are you trying to do by making the left `60vw`?

Comment: @InSync I'm trying to have two boxes that expand when hovered on. The reason I'm using grid is just because it seemed easiest to have an equal width blank space around and between the boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flexbox with [the `flex` short-hand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
}

.box {
  flex: 1; /* This makes boxes take equal space by default */
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.box:hover {
  flex: 2; /* A hovered box expands twice as fast as a non-hovered */
}
```

Try it:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.box:hover {
  flex: 2;
}


/* Demo only */

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
}

.box {
  height: 100%;
}

.one {
  background: pink;
}

.two {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box one"></div>
  <div class="box two"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote a detailed article about such effect that I invite you to read to understand how to achieve such effect using CSS grid: https://css-tricks.com/zooming-images-in-a-grid-layout/

```css
.container {
  height: calc(100vh - 2em);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  margin: 1em;
  gap: 1em;
}
.box {
  width: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}
.box:hover {
  width: 40vw; /* read the article to understand the math behind setting this value */
}

.one {background: pink;}
.two {background: red;}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box one"></div>
  <div class="box two"></div>
</div>
```